# auto in c++11 is static typing or dynamic typing

Tags: c++, c++11

Is auto command in c++11 is static binding(typing) or dynamic binding?

i.e. if i have this code

```
auto x = 5;
```

will the compiler decide that "x" is a int, or will it be descovered on runtime?

also, what will be the type of x in the following code?

```
auto x = 5, y = 4.5
```

Comment: **Static**. The compiler will deduce it from what you're assigning to it.

Comment: For `auto x = 5, y = 4.5;`, g++ gives: `error: inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'double'`

Comment: It is **type inference**, auto replaces spelled-out name for the result of the expression on rhs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called *type inference*. The typing is still *static*, but you leave the compiler figure out what the type of an expression is.

Specifically `auto x = 5;`, at compiler time, [is translated to `int x = 5;`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77164026a4c2ac25). For this very reason you have always to provide an unambiguous expression at initialization. For example `auto x;` [wouldn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/922d83823363d81f).